# Can't deploy Parse background job

Tags: javascript, heroku, parse-platform, background-process, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to get a 'hello world' background job running on heroku and then extend upon that, however whenever I try to deploy it I get the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

The code is as follows, and I have regular cloud functions that work just fine so I know Parse is initialized etc, what am I doing wrong here?

**Broken background job**

```
Parse.Cloud.job('myBackgroundJob', function(request, response)
{
    console.log('Running background job');
});
```

**Working cloud code function**

```
Parse.Cloud.define('sayHello', function(request, response)
{
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working using cron, using [this example](https://gist.github.com/gimdongwoo/326133fc6a471740a5ee73a3565e1b42) as a template:

If you do take this approach, I strongly recommend setting this up on a seperate 'worker' dyno instead of bundling with your main app, otherwise your jobs will run multiple times when adding more dynos.

Very simply to put the index.js code in another file, and then specify that file to be used for a worker dyno in your procfile.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that background jobs are not supported on Heroku, based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276035/how-to-move-cloud-code-from-parse-com-to-heroku).

Instead it appears you need to use [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) for less important jobs, or a [Custom Clock Process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes) for jobs that need to be executed more frequently or reliably.

If anyone has an example or tutorial of how to set this up, I would greatly appreciate it. In my case I need a Custom Clock Process.

Comment: For now I have just gone back to Parse Cloud Code. So far it seems okay, hopefully it doesn't ruin my life later.

Comment: For the record, going back did in fact ruin my life since they are shutting down Parse.com

Still looking for a tutorial on setting up a custom clock process for Parse + Heroku :(